# Prob. 25, Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: The assumption that $m\left(B_1\right)<\infty$ is necessary in ...

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-sets

Here is Prob. 25, Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden and P. M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Show that the assumption that $m\left( B_1 \right) < \infty$ is necessary in part (ii) of the theorem regarding continuity of measure.

Here is the theorem regarding continuity of measure (i.e. Theorem 15) in Royden:

> Lebesgue measure possesses the following continuity properties:

> (i) If $\left\{ A_k \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is an ascending collection of measurable sets, then
> $$
> m \left( \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k \right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} m \left( A_k \right).
> $$

> (ii) If $\left\{ B_k \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a descending collection of measurable sets and $m \left( B_1 \right) < \infty$, then
> $$
> m \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty B_k \right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} m \left( B_k \right).
> $$

My Attempt:

> For each positive integer $k$, let us put
> $$ 
> B_k := \big( k, \infty \big) = \big\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid k < x < \infty \big\}. 
> $$

> Then, for each $k$, we have
> $$
> B_k = \big( k, \infty \big) \supset \big( k+1, \infty \big) = B_{k+1}.
> $$

> And, by Proposition 8 every set $B_k$, being an interval, is measurable, and by Proposition 1 we have
> $$
> m \left( B_k \right) = m^* \left( B_k \right) = l \left( B_k \right) = \infty.
> $$
> Therefore
> $$
> \lim_{k \to \infty} m \left( B_k \right) = \infty. \tag{1}
> $$

> On the other hand, we note that
> $$
> \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty B_k = \emptyset, 
> $$
> because for every real number $a$ we can find a positive integer $k > a$, and thus $a \not\in B_k$ for any such $k$; therefore we obtain
> $$
> m \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty B_k \right) = 0. \tag{2}
> $$

> From (1) and (2) we conclude that part (ii) of Theorem 15 does not hold for this particular countable collection of measurable sets for which $m \left( B_1 \right) \not< \infty$.

Is my proof correct and clear enough? If not, then where are the issues?

Comment: Correct and clear.

Comment: In fact, the sharp assumption is that $m(B_{n_0})<+\infty$ for SOME $n_0\in\Bbb N$ and not necessrily the first subset. But in this case, you can skip the fist $n_0-1$ subsets and the global intersection will be the same. So, the only possible counterexample is ESSENTIALLY yours, that example in wich the measure of all subsets is $\infty$.